# Error Starting SQL Server - Network-Related or Instance-Specific Error

Tags: sql-server

When I try to start SQL Server, I get the following message.

[image]

I stopped the service, but now I can;t get it restarted.

It says there is a dependency on SQL Server Agent.  Now, When I look at SQL Server Agent, it says there is a dependency on SQL Server Express.

[image]

This can;t be right!  How can B have a dependency on A, while A has a dependency on B!?  I must be doing something wrong here, but I don;t know what it is.  Any thoughts on this, anyone?

Comment: Can you get to SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: Yes!  Under 'protocols for express' my TCP/IP is enabled and under 'client protocols' , also, my TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: Can you open SSMS and determine if remote connections are allowed on the database you seek?

Comment: Well, I can't connect to the server, so I can;t say for sure.  All I know, is that I closed the lid on my laptop, and when i got back on my machine about an hour later, I couldn't connect to the server.  I don;t know what changed here.  Apparently, some kind of setting changed, but I have no idea what!!

Comment: The picture says your instance is stopping. So it IS inaccessible (or was). Try rebooting your machine. Then verify that the instance has started. If it does not automatically start, then start it manually. And no - the picture does not say that the instance has a dependency on the agent. The lower box is the "xxx depends on this" area - the agent depends on the instance (which is irrelevant since express does not support the agent).

Comment: Yeap, yeap, a reboot quickly fixed the issue.  It was a little misleading because the message read 'stopping' but it said that for over an hour.  I was doing other things in the meantime.  Anyway, I guess something got mangled and the restart reset everything.  Thanks SMor!!